# Azure window server in-place upgrade but plan is still the same

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

In order to avoid doing some overhead work, I decide to use a work-around to upgrade my VM from server 2016 to 2019. The work around was successful and everything is running fine. One hiccup though is that I still see the plan being set to "2016-Datacenter".

(Correct me if I am wrong) So far doing some digging I see that this is set at the create time of the VM; it corresponds to the sku of the image used to build the VM.

My question is, are there any gotchas if the VM is running server 2019 but the plan is set to "2016-Datacenter"

Comment: @NancyXiong it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan information is metadata Microsoft uses to track Marketplace offers. If you want to create an image in a shared gallery, using a source that was originally created from an Azure Marketplace image like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/marketplace-images), you may need to keep track of purchase plan information. You may face issues when you create a VM from the Azure Marketplace image if there is wrong plan information. Read [here](https://samcogan.com/creating-vms-from-a-marketplace-image-that-needs-a-plan/) for more details.

We are able to do an Azure VM in-place upgrade to Windows Server 2019. [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-vm-upgrade-to-windows-server-2019) is the step by step process to update the IaaS VM Windows server to Windows Server 2019 for your reference.

However, it's not recommended to do because [Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of an Azure VM.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/in-place-system-upgrade). It prefers to use a clean uninstallation and installation. To work around this issue, create an Azure VM that's running a supported version of an operating system, and then migrate the workload.